# Migration from Richfaces 3.3.0 with JSF 1.2 to Richfaces 3.3.3 with JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, migration, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am using JSF 1.2 , Richfaces 3.3.0 , Maven2 with Tomcat 6. I am in need to migrate from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0 in order to get rid of problems raised in my project.

I had found that Richfaces 3.3.3 is a stepping stone to JSF 2.0 .

I know there is more effort in migration to Richfaces 4.0, Facelets 2.0 and JSF 2.0 from my spec referred in [Painfullness in Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)

I referred [JSF 2.0 and Richfaces 3.3.3](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces333andJSF20) and I need to upgrade only JSF.

My Question is

1. Can I upgrade JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0 and Richfaces 3.3.0 to Richfaces 3.3.3 and use only Facelet 1.1.15 (currently using, in order to minimise the effort).
2. Is there any major differenence between Richfaces 3.3.0 and 3.3.3.

Edit: Can I upgrade Richfaces from 3.3.0 to 3.3.3 without JSF upgradation.

Hope you can understand my query. Suggest me a solution to migrate.

Comment: 1) is already implicitly answered as "No" in that migration question you found.

Comment: @BalusC - In that migration page, it is said implicitly 'No'. Can I migrate it page by page and as well as component by component. If so, what to do.